# Google auth for YouTube doesn't work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, rubygems, google-oauth

I'm using Rails 5.1.1 an [yt gem 0.28](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt)

I used official gem docs (link is above).

Also these docs [Github](https://fullscreen.github.io/yt/videos.html)

And tried to check myself with this tutorial on [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/youtube-api-version-3-rails/)

If you check comments below the SP's tutorial - there was the same issue but yt owner removed Issues so I can't use it.

Gem seems to be working fine. At least when I place:

```
video = Yt::Video.new id: 'BPNYv0vd78A'
```

in video_controllers.rb and then ask for video.description, it answers with description. So lets put a tick here.

And I cofigured YT as it was said:

```
Yt.configure do |config|
    config.log_level = :debug
    config.client_id = "[my_client_id].apps.googleusercontent.com"
    config.client_secret = "[my_secret_key]"
    config.api_key = '[my_api_key]'
end
```

I copied values from google_oauth2, so if there it's OK, it must be OK here as well.

But when I try to use anything involving authentification something very strange happens.

FIRST PART - access token

According to the manual, if I have access token I can just:

```
account = Yt::Account.new access_token: 'ya29.[authenticating_user_token]'
account.email
```

Here goes the message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Also it offers curl command to simulate this action:

```
curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" -H "authorization: Bearer ya29.[authenticating_user_token]" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?key=[my_api_key]"
```

authenticating_user_token is the same as I get from google auth json like `user.auth_hash["credentials"]["token"]`
my_api_key is the same key from Google Developers Console.

When I requested account's value through byebug, it gave me:

```
#<Yt::Models::Account:0x000000051473f0 @access_token="ya29.[authenticating_user_token]", @refresh_token=nil, @device_code=nil, @expires_at=nil, @authorization_code=nil, @redirect_uri=nil, @force=nil, @scopes=nil, @authentication=nil>
```

The first question that stays without answer: "***Why it uses api key if docs say all I need is access_token?***"

SECOND PART refresh_token

Actually, after the fiasco with access token I thought that it might be that

```
"credentials"=>{"token"=>"ya29.[authenticating_user_token]",
"expires"=>true,
"expires_at"=>1518443279}
```

is the mysterious refresh token!

It gave me the same 'Invalid Credentials'

So I modified videos_controller.rb:

```
      account = Yt::Account.new(refresh_token: user.auth_hash["credentials"]["token"],
      expires_at: user.auth_hash["credentials"]["expires_at"],
      expires: user.auth_hash["credentials"]["expires"])
```

This time with byebug I got account's value:

```
#<Yt::Models::Account:0x00000007a6e5a8 @access_token=nil, @refresh_token="ya29.[you know_what]", @device_code=nil, @expires_at=1518443279, @authorization_code=nil, @redirect_uri=nil, @force=nil, @scopes=nil, @authentication=nil, @user_infos=#<Yt::Collections::UserInfos:0x00000007a305a0 @parent=#<Yt::Models::Account:0x00000007a6e5a8 ...>, @auth=#<Yt::Models::Account:0x00000007a6e5a8 ...>, @page_token=nil, @last_index=0, @items=[]>, @refreshed_authentications=#<Yt::Collections::Authentications:0x007ff0080054b0 @parent=#<Yt::Models::Account:0x00000007a6e5a8 ...>, @auth=#<Yt::Models::Account:0x00000007a6e5a8 ...>, @auth_params={:client_id=>"[my_client_id].apps.googleusercontent.com", :client_secret=>"[my_client_secret]", :refresh_token=>"[you_know_what]", :grant_type=>:refresh_token}, @page_token=nil, @last_index=1, @items=[], @where_params={}>>
```

And requesting account.email:

```
*** Yt::Errors::Unauthorized Exception: A request to YouTube API was sent without a valid authentication:
{}

You can retry the same request manually by running:





nil
```

And the second question: "***Was it refresh token or not?***"

In YouTube account I have a working channel so it couldn't be a reason.

***I would appreciate any help! If you have any app working with YouTube, please share the link to Github, so I could figure out what's wrong with my app!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's embarssing - nobody even tried to help...

Still I found the source of errors.
So the token from auth["credentials"]["token"] is access token.

My problems came because I didn't specify :scope in config/initializers/device.rb
It should be:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "[client_id_from_google_developers_console].apps.googleusercontent.com", "[key_from_google_developers_console]", scope: 'userinfo.profile, userinfo.email, youtube'
```

Also I noticed the error comes when a token expires, so you should do something like begin-rescue thing to update user's token time-to-time.

Answer (score -5):

```
btn-group
use this class for the button div like <div class="btn-group"></div>
and apply 

btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.btn-group:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; 
}
```